# virtual memory size while multiple processes are running

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

My question is about the virtual memory size while lots of processes are running

1. Are identical amounts of virtual memory provided to every process?
2. If not, can the virtual memory size be changed dynamically (while the program is running)?
3. As far as I know, the virtual memory size is [limited by the RAM + swap area size](https://serverfault.com/a/774916). Is it the total sum of all the processes or just a single process that the memory size of which is limited by the RAM + swap area size? (I suspect the former would be the case but want to make it sure)

Answer (score 0):

The operating system provides a logical address space to each process. The size of that logical address space usually implemented such that it is the same for all processes. A 32-bit system might divide the logical address space such that the lower half is user address and the upper half is system addresses.

Addresses 0-2147483647 would be available to the user logical address space.
Operating systems frequently limit the size of the user address space, often a a configurable setting. the system manager could then limit the logical user address space to, say, 0-1073741823. reducing the logical address space reduces the amount of system space required for page tables. Usually this setting affects all processes but, in theory an added complexity, you could do it on an a per process basis.

> 1. Are identical amounts of virtual memory provided to every process?

Usually, processes start with virtual memory in the system space that is the same for all processes an no virtual memory in the user space.

> 2. If not, can the virtual memory size be changed dynamically (while the program is running)?

The size of the virtual address space changes constantly at a process starts off. It usually levels off after a while.

> As far as I know, the virtual memory size is limited by the RAM + swap area size(https://serverfault.com/a/774916). Is it the total sum of all the processes or just a single process that the memory size of which is limited by the RAM + swap area size? (I suspect the former would be the case but want to make it sure)

The virtual memory size is limited by all kinds of factors. Usually, the system parameters are the limit.